# Replace DataTables data and column headers

Tags: javascript, datatables

I can successfully replace the DataTable's data, but not the columns.  I am sure I can figure out how to change the column header text, however, this will not work should the column count change.  How should one replace both the data and the column header names?

```
var dataTables;
document.getElementById('query-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = getUrl();
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(this.response);
            if (dataTables) {
                console.log(dataTables)
                dataTables.clear();
                dataTables.rows.add(json.results.data);
                //dataTables.columns.add(json.results.columns);
                dataTables.draw();
            }
            else {
                dataTables = $('#datatables').DataTable( {
                    data: json.results.data,
                    columns: json.results.columns,
              } );
            }
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", url);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhttp.send();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your data call response like data and column array then put my code in your ajax call or any other calls and solve your dynamic column problem in DataTables.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var dataObject = eval('[{"COLUMNS": [{ "title": "Col1"}, { "title": "Col2"}], "DATA":[["RP","1"],["Billy","2"],["GP","3"],["MM","4"]]}]');
    var columns = [];
    $('#demoexample').dataTable({
        "data": dataObject[0].DATA,
        "columns": dataObject[0].COLUMNS
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I can create the initial DataTable as shown by my original post, but cannot make changes to the header names after initialing rendering.  My current workaround is to first destroy it and then re-initialize it.  Thanks